# msg.guild.roles.find isn't a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I don't really know why it's causing this issue, In order that I have my discord.js up to date

`TypeError: msg.guild.roles.find is not a function`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: [`Guild.roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles) returns a [RoleManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager). You can use the resolve functions to get a role from a snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

Since discord.js v12 accessing the `roles` collection can be done through the `cache` property.

`msg.guild.roles.cache.find()`

Answer (score 0):

The above error is caused due to the '***find***' method not being available in Discord.js library.

Discord.js has a '***fetch***' method instead. It can be called using:

```
message.guild.roles.fetch()
```

**More information:**

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/RoleManager

Answer (score 0):

If you have got discord.js version 12, you can use @Syntle solution, or there is also [`msg.guild.roles.fetch(id,[cache])`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=fetch). I think, that this is better, because the role dont have to be cached.